# how to eliminate "not" in expression using z3?

Tags: z3

I try to use the code to remove not in the expression:

```
(declare-const t Int)

(assert (and (or (>= t 2) (>= t 1)) (not (= t 1))))

(apply ctx-solver-simplify)
```

I want to get the result like: t >= 2
However, the result is:

```
(goals
(goal
  (>= t 1)
  (not (= t 1))
  :precision precise :depth 1)
)
```

would some one help me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The tactic `simplify` has an option `:eq2ineq`. When enabled, it will convert an equality `t1 = t2` into `t1 <= t2 and t1 >= t2`. After applying this tactic, the tactic `propagate-ineqs` will be more effective.

Here is a script that does the trick:
http://rise4fun.com/Z3/JWit

Note that, this is not a general solution. None of the builtin tactics do exactly what you want.

Comment: yes, it is not a general solution, I tried an another example, it doesn't work. So that is to say, in general, we can not remove "not" from the expression?

Comment: I thought your goal was to get a simpler/smaller expression. In principle, for arithmetic, it is possible to eliminate all `not`-expressions by applying transformations such as: `not t <= s ---> t > s`, `not t = s  ---> (t < s or t > s)`. However, this does not work for other theories. For example, we can't eliminate the `not` in `not t = s` when `t` and `s` are, for example, arrays. Of course, I'm assuming that the expression `distinct(t, s)` is just a `not t = s` in "disguise". BTW, would a tactic that eliminates all `not`-expressions in arithmetic formulas be useful for you?

Comment: there is case that does't work, here is the script: [link](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/XwGt)

Comment: sorry, the tactic doesn't eliminate all not-expressions for me, here is the script, there is still not in the expression， http://rise4fun.com/Z3/XwGt  thanks for help